# Como saber que objeto es el que esta en la lista

Tags: java, lista

Amigos tengo una aplicacion que contien una clase Animales de la cual hereda la clase mamiferos con sus atributos y de esta heredan dos clases carnivoros y herbivoros. Ahora en una clase zoologico tengo una lista de Animales la cual va a almacenar dos tipos de objetos solamente (Carnivoros o herbivoros). Ahora en la misma clase zoologico quiero en un metodo acceder si es Carnivoro el objeto a un atributo determinado y si es Herbivoro a una atributo de herbivoro. Como hacer que el programa identifique que objeto es y me de su atributo particular.
Gracias...

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(object instanceof Herviboro){
  object.metodoHerviboro();
}else if(object instanceof Carnivoro){
  object.metodoCarnivoro();
}
```

De esta forma compruebas si un objeto es una instancia de una determinada clase.

Comment: Este wey SAPEE!!, tambien se puede hacer a lo cavernicola, colocando los 2 metodos en la clase padre pero vacios, y en la clase Herviboro colocar el metodo pero con el codigo, y asi en la clase Carniboro, pero es mejor haciendo el Instanceof, Saludos!